# "Mark insisted that he would be the one who <told> <tells> <will tell> <would tell> John the bad news."

Tags: subordinate-clauses, future-in-the-past

**(1)** *Mark insists that he will be the one who **tells** John the bad news*.
**(2)** *Mark insists that he will be the one who **will tell** John the bad news*.
Do (1) and (2) mean the same? If not, then why not?

Variants of backshifting (1):
**(1a)** *Mark insisted that he would be the one who **tells** John the bad news*. — what does "*tells*" mean here?
**(1b)** *Mark insisted that he would be the one who **told** John the bad news*. — what does "*told*" mean here?
What's the difference between (1a) and (1b)?

Variants of backshifting (2):
**(2a)** *Mark insisted that he would be the one who **will tell** John the bad news*. — "*will tell*" means Mark hasn't told John the bad news yet
**(2b)** *Mark insisted that he would be the one who **would tell** John the bad news*. — "*would tell*" means we don't know whether Mark has already told John the bad news or not
Are my explanations of (2a) and (2b) correct? If not, then why not?

P.S.: the question arose because when I saw (1b) (on [wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/he-had-insisted-the-day-before.3461718/post-17564597)) I wanted to find out why "*told*" was used.

Comment: Told or would tell -- or to tell.

Comment: @LukeSawczak You wrote "or to tell". Could you write the full sentence you meant with it? Thanks.

Comment: Mark insisted that he would be the one to tell John the bad news.

Comment: @LukeSawczak you wrote "told" from (1b) and "would tell" from (2b) are correct. Does it mean "tells" from (1a) and "will tell" from (2a) are incorrect? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "told" was used because it's *reported speech* due to the reporting verb "insisted".

This allows all verbs in Marc's original statement to be *optionally* backshifted. This choice of backshifting is the only difference between your versions (a) and (b).

So in the context where nobody has told John the bad news yet, (1a) and (1b) are identical in meaning.

Sentences (1) and (2) mean near enough the same thing that it's probably not worth picking over, and the answer to that question is distant enough from this one about reported speech that it should be a separate question.

Comment: If, as you said, (1) ≈ (2), then this means two things: (1a) ≈ (2a) and (1b) ≈ (2b). Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii That's right.